# Change the footer on the homepage

Tags: xml, html, footer

I would like to change only the `footer` of the `homepage`, I know how to change only one page per `xml`, but according to `module`, `controller` and etc,

how would you do that for `homepage`? Display a `different footer`?

Comment: You can use **"Layout Update XML"** from CMS Page at **"home"** URL Key

Comment: It is not a cms page, it was made in phtml ..

Comment: Yes, I know, but you can modify render another PHTML file from **"Layout Update XML"** CMS Page, in this textarea (Layout Update XML) from CMS Page you can change layout same from layout XML for homepage.